# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' masalah = 'dsd' AND gambar = 'kerusi.JPG'' at line 1

Tags: mysql

I want to add record to a table which contain a picture. when i try to add, it shows me this error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' masalah = 'dsd' AND gambar = 'kerusi.JPG'' at line 1

so, here are the code

```
<?php

session_start();
include("Connections/connection.php");

$date = $_POST['date'];
$masalah = $_POST ['masalah'];
$gambar = $_POST ['gambar'];
$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$status = 'pending';

/*session yg di call tok lecturer tu*/

$student_id = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_id ='".$_SESSION['student_id']."'" ;
$result=mysql_query($student_id);
$getstudentid = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$student_id = $getstudentid['student_id'];

/*take 3 data from rc   */

$sql = "SELECT * FROM aduan WHERE date = '$date', masalah = '$masalah' AND  gambar = '$gambar' ";

$rr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$tt = mysql_num_rows($rr);

if($tt > 0) {

    header("Location: borang_aduan2.php?error=2");

} else { /*to check tarikh*/

    $tarikh_user = strtotime($date); 
    $tarikh_harini = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')); 

    if($tarikh_user < $tarikh_harini) {
        //error
        header("Location: borang_aduan2.php?error=1");
    } else {

                //$No = $num_rows+1;
        /*$sql_const = mysql_query ("Select MAX(user_name)as id from lecturer")or die (mysql_error());
        $rows = mysql_fetch_array ($sql_const);
        $id = $rows ['id'];*/

    /*insert data*/

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO aduan (date, masalah, gambar, student_id )
        VALUES('$date','$masalah', '$gambar','$student_id')")  

        or die('Error: ' .mysql_error($conn));
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Thanks make a report!')
            location.href='borang_aduan2.php'
            </script>";


        }

        //Freeing all memory associated with it
        mysql_free_result($result);
        //Closes specified connection
        mysql_close($conn);
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Please be aware that code might be vulnerable of SQL injections. To fix this vulnerability you should escape user-input when it is embedded in a query.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use "," in between two field selection criteria. So instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM aduan WHERE date = '$date', 
                                        ^^
```

Use

```
SELECT * FROM aduan WHERE date = '$date' AND
```